# Draw object in opengl depending on x,y coordinate given by various input devices

Tags: opengl, mouseevent

I have multiple input devices and I want to create a cursor for each one. I'm given x and y coordinates, and I want to draw it on the screen.

How do I calculate the x,y when using glTranslatef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, unless im suffering from a major mind failure, it goes as follows:

```
float fX  = ((float)(x * 2) / (float)screenWidth) - 1.0f)
float fY  = ((float)(-y * 2) / (float)screenHeight) - 1.0f)
```

Comment: hi yup it works :) thank you so much

although it should be

float fY  = (((float)(y * 2) / (float)screenHeight) - 1.0f)*-1.0f;

Comment: yeah fair enough .. I had a feeling i was getting the reverse on the y-axis wrong :)